# Install newer version of lua-expat for prosody on 14.04

Tags: apt, ubuntu-14.04, repository

I'm on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` and running `lua-expat 1.2.0-6` the newest [version for Trusty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lua-expat).
Prosody throws this error:

> The version of LuaExpat on your system does not support stanza size
> limits, which may leave servers on untrusted networks (e.g. the
> internet) vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks. You should upgrade
> to LuaExpat 1.3.0 or higher as soon as possible. See
> http://prosody.im/doc/depends#luaexpat for more information.

How can I / What is the best way to install a newer version of lua-expat?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [this](https://bremensaki.com/2015/03/20/modules-and-dependencies/) blog post …

There you will find the answer: install `luarocks` :)

Short:

```
# apt-get install luarocks libexpat-dev
# luarocks install luaexpat
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably: 
Use a ppa (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas), e.g.
https://launchpad.net/~patrick-georgi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
which provides lua-expat 1.3.0-0.1

Comment: Note that this PPA is created by user [Patrick Georgi](https://launchpad.net/~patrick-georgi), who has 0 karma and is otherwise inactive in on Launchpad.